# how to delete or update script on cdn.jsdelivr.com?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script to read URL parameters with github and I input it into jsdelivr.com, but I see someone else is using that script, my question is can the script that has been entered into cdn.jsdelivr.com be changed or updated?

the thing i have done is change the code in github, but after i check in cdn.jsdelivr.com it is still the same and not changed.

**Edit: jsdelivr.com has update after 3 hours, after im edit on github.com**

Github: [code on github after change](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pendekin/prohe/main/gotgetv2.js)

jsdelivr: [code on jsdelivr.com still not change](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pendekin/prohe@main/gotgetv2.js)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It needs times to renew the file, access the file via jsDelivr after pushing to GitHub. Then wait for about an hour.